# C++ How to fix multiple declaration compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have 2 headers and one cpp file.
Block.h:

```
    #ifndef BLOCK_H
    #define BLOCK_H

    namespace storage {

    class Block {
    };

    } // namespace storage

    #endif // BLOCK_H
```

PerformanceWriteTest.h

```
    #ifndef _PERFORMANCE_WRITE_TEST_
    #define _PERFORMANCE_WRITE_TEST_

    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using std::vector;

    class Block;  // <<< Forward declaration of Block

    class PerformanceWriteTest {
      vector<Block*> blocks_;
    public:
      virtual ~PerformanceWriteTest();
    };

    #endif
```

PerformanceWriteTest.cpp

```
    #include "Block.h"
    #include "PerformanceWriteTest.h"

    using storage::Block; // <<< Use the scope storage::Block. Error!

    PerformanceWriteTest::~PerformanceWriteTest() {
      for (Block* block : blocks_) {
        delete block;
      }
    }
```

Visual Studio 2012 gives me the error:
error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'storage::Block'

Is it possible to avoid this error without moving the using directive and include "Block.h" to the header?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_PERFORMANCE_WRITE_TEST_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have two "Blocks" declared.  One is inside namespace "storage" and the other is in the global namespace. Try this:

```
namespace storage {
    class Block;  // <<< Forward declaration of Block
}
class PerformanceWriteTest {
   vector<storage::Block*> blocks_;
 public:
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the forward declaration in the header inside the namespace:

```
namespace storage
{
    class Block; 
}
```

and

```
vector<storage::Block*> blocks_;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the error message that is the problem here. It should say:

> using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'Block'

and not

> using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'storage::Block'

In any case, your forward declaration `class Block;` declares `Block` in the global namespace, so it is not the same class as `storage::Block`. Thus your `using`-directive gives two meanings to `Block`, which is not allowed.